# How to manually enter a cell in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

This is my dataframe:

```
county          state   cases deaths  FIPS
Abbeville   South Carolina   4      0 45001
Acadia      Louisiana        9      1 22001
Accomack    Virginia         3      0 51001
New York C  New York         2      0 NA
Ada         Idaho           113     2 16001
Adair       Iowa             1      0 19001
```

I would like to manually put "55555" into the NA cell. My actual df is thousands of lines long and the row where the NA changes based on the day. I would like to add based on the county. Is there a way to say `df[df$county == "New York C",] <- df$FIPS = "55555"` or something like that? I don't want to insert based on the column or row number because they change.

Answer (score 1):

This will put `55555` into the `NA` cells within column `FIPS` where `country` is `New York C`

```
df$FIPS[is.na(df$FIPS) & df$county == "New York C"] <- 55555
```

**Output**

```
df

#   county     state          cases deaths FIPS 
# 1 Abbeville  South Carolina     4      0 45001
# 2 Acadia     Louisiana          9      1 22001
# 3 Accomack   Virginia           3      0 51001
# 4 New York C New York           2      0 55555
# 5 Ada        Idaho            113      2 16001
# 6 Adair      Iowa               1      0 19001
# 7 New York C New York           1      0 18000
```

**Data**

```
df

#   county     state          cases deaths  FIPS
# 1 Abbeville  South Carolina     4      0 45001
# 2 Acadia     Louisiana          9      1 22001
# 3 Accomack   Virginia           3      0 51001
# 4 New York C New York           2      0    NA
# 5 Ada        Idaho            113      2 16001
# 6 Adair      Iowa               1      0 19001
# 7 New York C New York           1      0 18000
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `&` (and) to substitute de `df$FIPS` entries that meet the two desired conditions.

```
df$FIPS[is.na(df$FIPS) & df$state=="New York"]<-5555
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change values based on multiple conditions, I'd go with `dplyr::mutate()`.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  mutate(FIPS = ifelse(is.na(FIPS) & county == "New York C", 55555, FIPS))
```